# Issuing caching results of REST service created using ServiceStack and accessed through jQuery

Tags: servicestack

I have a REST service created using ServiceStack that I'm consuming from jQuery running in a mobile browser.  Everything works fine until I attempt to implement caching within the service using the MemoryCacheClient.  As soon as I insert the code to cache the results I don't get any response returned to the browser.  When I look at the request\response in Fiddler I get the following error:

Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection.  Click here to transform.

If I just access the service directly from the browser it works fine, it only seems to be an issue when accessed through .ajax method in jQuery.

Here's the service code

```
public override object OnGet(Products request)
        {
            string cacheKey =
                UrnId.Create<ProductsService>("productCategoryType", request.ProductCategoryType.ToString());

            return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey, () =>
            {
                //var service = this.ResolveService<ProductsService>();
                ProductsResponse response = new ProductsResponse();
                response.Products = GetLoanTypes(request.ProductCategoryType);
                return response;
            });
        }
```

And then the Ajax

```
    var serviceUrl = "http://local.standard.id.com/MobileServices/Products/";
    var products = new Object();
    products.ProductCategoryType = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: products,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                productData[id] = data;
                displayProducts(data, id);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

As soon as I comment out the caching in the service and just always return the raw results everything works fine.